# Still Unable to Unlock Personal Account in Geth - Syntax Errors, GoError

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

In my MacBook Terminal -> Geth,

I have successfully created my new -> personal.newAccount(0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176)  along with its given generated password.

I’m still unable to “Unlock Account” as I keep getting errors though I have tried the following commands along with their errors shown:

> geth --unlock ‘0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176’ --password ‘0x9169b03a06ba19b44f4237772e5a8dd0f1124094’
> SyntaxError: (anonymous): Line 1:8 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176)
> GoError: password must be a string
> at native
> at :1:41(7)

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176, 0x9169b03a06ba19b44f4237772e5a8dd0f1124094)
> GoError: password must be a string
> at native
> at :1:85(8)

> web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], “0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176”)
> SyntaxError: (anonymous): Line 1:50 Unexpected token ILLEGAL (and 3 more errors)

> web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176, 0x9169b03a06ba19b44f4237772e5a8dd0f1124094, 600)
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'unlockAccount' of undefined
> at :1:1(4)

> web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(‘0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176’, ‘0x9169b03a06ba19b44f4237772e5a8dd0f1124094’, 600)
> SyntaxError: (anonymous): Line 1:33 Unexpected token ILLEGAL (and 5 more errors)

> web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176, "0x9169b03a06ba19b44f4237772e5a8dd0f1124094")web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 0xA93d5aC3B28587DA16E4821F571ACF44B6B28176, "0x9169b03a06ba19b44f4237772e5a8dd0f1124094")
> SyntaxError: (anonymous): Line 1:139 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)

I need help in this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not unlock!!! That is a very very bad and unused practice, please sing ur transactions with the private key or use ganache for simulation

Comment: I did not unlock it. I just want to add my ETH Account into Geth only. Fine, I will not lock it but do you know the command line in Geth to "Add" my New ETH Account instead of creating new.PersonalAccount itself? Appreciate your reply, thanks.

Comment: I don’t understand what are u trying to do, if u have already a wallet then you can copy the json  file data in the keys folder of geth

Comment: Sorry to make you confused. This is what I want to do. I want to send transaction to my ETH Account in Kraken from Geth. That is why the Unlock Account occurs. I did "Add" the ETH Account from Kraken in Geth, and no solutions available. You did mentioned that I can copy JSON file data in the keys folder of Geth? Is that possible with Kraken Account? How?

Comment: If u have a private key of the ethereum address or the json file + password then just import it in metamask and send what u like to send. No need for geth or other stuff. Make sure ur are using the correct metamask and not a clone, and don’t give ur keys or password or json file to anyone